# Linear topology

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, neighbourhood

**Definition**: A linear topology $\tau$ on a left $A$-module $M$ is a topology on $M$ that is invariant under translations and admits a fundamental system of neighborhood of $0$ that consists of submodules of $M$.

From this definition, let $\mathcal{F}$ be a fundamental system of neighborhood of $0$ consisting of submodules of $M$. Since $\{0\}$ is a submodule of $M$, then $\{0\}\in\mathcal{F}$. Can we say that the linear topology on $M$ is a discrete topology? Because $\{0\}$ is in $\mathcal{F}$ implies $a+\{0\}=\{a\}$ is an open set in $M$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The fundamental system consists of submodules of $M$, but the trivial submodule $0$ is not assumed to be there... To have an example, consider the ring $A$ to be the ring of $p$-adic integers, $\Bbb Z_p$. Let $M$ be the field $\Bbb Q_p$. Then $p^{-n}\Bbb Z_p$ with $n$ in the integers is such a fundamental system. But the trivial module is not part of the family.

Comment: I got it. The trivial submodule $\{0\}$ is in $\mathcal{N}(M)$ the collection of all neighbourhoods 0 of $M$ and $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{N}(M)$. Thank you for considering my question.

Comment: @YSA I don't think you got it. In the example of $p$-adic numbers $\{0\}$ is not a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: Just to spell it out, I guess the key distinction being missed is that "consisting of submodules" does not mean "consisting of ALL submodules", just some.